# How to run GWTP Project?

Tags: java, gwt, gwt-platform

When I try to run a sample project from GWTP Repo after import it to eclipse and run it as GWT Project, when access to the page, this show up:

> To launch an application, specify a
>   URL of the form /module/file.html

I wonder what is the problem with my setup here.

Thank you very much.

Comment: It most likely means there was an error while building the project - check the output/logs carefully - the exception/error should be there somewhere :)

Comment: It was a success build. Without any error.

Comment: And when you say when access to the page" - which page were you accessing?

Comment: I mean the very first default page of the application. in this case: localhost:8888 . I have no idea what happened. This application is the same as this: http://gwtpsample.appspot.com/ . I think i did something wrong. What i did is import and compile, and run as GWT Project

Comment: Like the error says - you should specify the full url - it won't redirect you from localhost:8888 to whatever your project's name is. The full url you should be visiting should be printed out in Eclipse's console.

Comment: so how to make this work. It was simply a singple page application. that one is the root. Beside eclipse did not popout the full URL.

Comment: Could you provide a link to the sample project you are trying to run?

Comment: https://samples.gwt-platform.googlecode.com/hg/ you can get it using mecury here. Thank you :)

Comment: I don't have Mercury available atm, but you should be able to access your application at http://localhost:8888/[moduleName].html, like: http://localhost:8888/GWTSample.html. Check the war directory for for an HTML file. Also, are you using Google's Eclipse Plugin?

Answer (score 0):

Try to add GWT SDK Library in the classpath of the project (Eclipse -> right click on the project ->Properties -> Libraries tab -> Add Library) and then by Order and Export tab move the GWT SDK Library on Top (press Top button).